# Boss RC-300 Audio interface appears but no sound is heard

Tags: usb, sound, interface, external-soundcard

I got a new RC-300 Loop Station...Nice Looper!
But now I want to you use the Audio-interface of it and have some problems. If I do the following:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards /proc/asound/module
0 [VirMIDI ]: VirMIDI - VirMIDI
Virtual MIDI Card 1
...
4 [RC300 ]: USB-Audio - RC-300
BOSS RC-300 at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, high speed
```

The RC300 appears in Jack. But I can't get it as Audio-Source for Jack. Every time I select the RC300 as input jack crashes.

And also in my Patch-Bay the Audio Source/Sink of the RC300 does not appear....only the Midi is available

Maybe my configuration is totally wrong :-) I'm not a Ubuntu/Linux pro...

I don't think that the Jack configuration is the problem.
I read something about a missing entry @ quirks-table.h but I don't think that this is my problem, as when I enter `aplay -l` my RC-300 is listed:

```
$ aplay -l
Karte 1: RC300 [RC-300], Gerät 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
```

Maybe it's the same problem as in this topic....but there is no solution

Comment: please put in the link to the topic

Comment: sorry I forgot the link. Here it is:

Comment: https://linuxmusicians.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=16394&p=76258&hilit=audio+interface#p76258